Singularity or stiff of system suspected
I have the following system of differential equations:
$$\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt} = rx\left(1-\frac xK\right)-\beta x-axz, \\ \frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dt} = \beta x - \frac{\eta yz}{y+m} - \mu y, \\ \frac{\mathrm dz}{\mathrm dt} = \alpha_1 xz + \rho z^2 - \frac{\eta_1 yz}{y+m}$$
with parametric values $r=0.82$, $\beta=0.87$, $\alpha=1.56$, $\alpha_1=1.12$, $\eta=2.41$, $\eta_1=1.83$, $K=12$, $\rho=1.38$, $m=0.13$, and $\mu=0.11$. Solving it using NDSolve and plotting it gives unexpected results: at $t=0.16430198024431886$, singularity or stiff system is suspected. I am trying to iterate the plotting taking reference from
Dian Savitri 2019 J. Phys.: Conf. Ser. 1417 012025
where the system has been seemingly plotted as follows:

However the result that I get after solving the system on Mathematica (find code below) looks like this:

After $t=0.16430198024431886$, there seems to be no solution at all. I have tried it with Python: scipy library as well, and the result is similar:

I need help with where is the issue, and how the research article I am referencing may have solved this error.
JuvenilePrey := 
  x'[t] == r x[t] (1 - x[t]/k) - \[Beta] x[t] - \[Alpha] x[t] z[t];
AdultPrey := 
  y'[t] == \[Beta] x[t] - (\[Eta] y[t] z[t])/(y[t] + m) - \[Mu] y[t];
Predator := 
  z'[t] == \[Alpha]1 x[t] z[t] + \[Rho] z[t]^2 - (\[Eta]1 y[t] z[t])/(
    y[t] + m);
parameters = {r -> .82, \[Beta] -> .87, \[Alpha] -> 1.56, \[Alpha]1 ->
     1.12, \[Eta] -> 2.41, \[Eta]1 -> 1.83, k -> 12, \[Rho] -> 1.38, 
   m -> 0.13, \[Mu] -> 0.11};
de1 = NDSolve[{{JuvenilePrey, AdultPrey, Predator} /. parameters, 
   x[0] == 3.01, y[0] == 5.05, z[0] == 4.28}, {x, y, z}, {t, 0, 10}, 
  Method -> "ExplicitRungeKutta"]
Plot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t], z[t]} /. de1], {t, 1, 3}]


Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! Please edit the question and include a complete Mathematica code that you are using so that we can reproduce your results. Also, have you tried with Method -> "StiffnessSwitching" in NDSolve?

@Domen.—I have edited my question. It includes the source code now. I had tried Method -> "StiffnessSwitching", however it only gives a different type of weird plot,,,

I replaced all constants like .82 and 4.28 with 82/100 and 428/100. I included the WorkingPrecision->256 inside NDSolve The resulting plot shows a jump at t==2 I tried a plot with {t,0,10} and it still shows the jump at 2 and x,y,z are growing exponentially with increasing t I tried Plot range to {t,0,3} to match your NDSolve and the plot blows up before it gets to t==0.2 I tried StiffnessSwitching with a Plot range {t,0,3} and it is very slow and blows up before t==0.1

I think there is something weird going on in their plots. Just look at the initial values of $x, y, z$ on the plot. They are certainly not [3.01. 5.05. 4.28] as written in the text ...

@Domen.—I had the same doubt at some point, but then I realised that the plot range is $[1, 3]$. So, maybe... the initial values are for $t = 0$. Regardless, I am still skeptical about the plots or the results they have got using this system. I have tried RK4 method to solve it too, and similar results are there. I think I should just try to contact the author and ask for help directly.

Yes indeed, you should ask directly the author. It is not worth to spend time guessing what might be wrong.

If $z$ comes to dominate $x$ and $y$, then the 3rd DE is in effect $z' = \rho z^2$, which has a solution $1/[\rho,(t-t_0)]$ where $t_0$ is near where NDSolve stops. This is exactly what this shows: t0 = x["Domain"] /. de1 // Flatten // Last; z'[t]/z[t]^2 /. t -> t0 /. de1 equals $\rho$ to ~8 dec. pl.).

There is a typo in predator equation. We can compare Jacobian to that in the paper as follows
 D[{r  x[t] (1 - x[t]/k) - \[Beta] x[t] - \[Alpha] x[t]  z[
      t], \[Beta]  x[t] - \[Eta] y[t] z[t]/(y[t] + m) - \[Mu]  y[
      t], \[Alpha]1  x[t] z[t] + \[Rho] z[t]^2 - \[Eta]1 y[
      t]  z[t]/(y[t] + m)}, {{x[t], y[t], z[t]}}] // MatrixForm


We see that on the last line second term is not same as in a paper. Therefore, we can repair system of equations using $J$ in a form
{r = 0.82, \[Beta] = 0.87, \[Alpha] = 1.56, \[Alpha]1 = 1.12, \[Eta] =
   2.41, \[Eta]1 = 1.83, \[Rho] = 1.38, k = 12, 
 m = 1.01, \[Mu] = 
  0.11}; eqs = {x'[t] == 
   r  x[t] (1 - x[t]/k) - \[Beta]  x[t] - \[Alpha]  x[t]  z[t], 
  y'[t] == \[Beta]  x[t] - \[Eta]  y[t] z[t]/(y[t] + m) - \[Mu]  y[t],
   z'[t] == \[Alpha]1  x[t] z[
      t] + \[Rho]  z[t]^2 - \[Eta]1   z[t]^2/(y[t] + m)};
ic = {x[1] == 3.01, y[1] == 5.05, z[1] == 4.28};
sol = NDSolve[{eqs, ic}, {x, y, z}, {t, 1, 3}];
Plot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t], z[t]} /. sol[[1]]], {t, 1, 3}, 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> {x, y, z}]


The drawing is similar to what was published in the article but there is no complete coincidence. I also greatly increased the parameter m. But we can already work with this system.

Thank you very much for your help. I had contacted the author after trying different things, none of which worked out. While I have not received a response, but certainly you have already answered my question. Have a great day...

@n11 You are welcome!
